# How to cast CheckBox to HasChangeHandler

Tags: java, gwt, checkbox

```
CheckBox faxGen = new CheckBox();
((HasChangeHandlers) faxGen).addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler(){
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) 
    {
        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox) event.getSource(); 
        FixedWidthGrid parent = (FixedWidthGrid) chkBox.getParent();
        Iterator<Integer> selectedRows = parent.getSelectedRows().iterator();
        Integer rowIdx = selectedRows.hasNext() ? selectedRows.next() : -1;
        boolean checked = chkBox.getValue() == true ? true : false;
        setCheckBoxRowSelected(rowIdx, checked, true);
        if (checked){
            pagingScrollTable.getDataTable().getRowFormatter().setStylePrimaryName(rowIdx, "grid2-body-row-hover");
        }
        else
        {
            pagingScrollTable.getDataTable().getRowFormatter().removeStyleName(rowIdx, "grid2-body-row-hover");
            pagingScrollTable.getDataTable().getRowFormatter().removeStyleName(rowIdx, "selected");
        }
        pagingScrollTable.getDataTable().getRowFormatter().removeStyleName(rowIdx, "highlighted selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question body so that you properly describe the problem you are having and your question. Take a read of [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: A piece of code with no explanation is not a question. Try again, please.

Comment: The question is "How to cast CheckBox to HasChangeHandler." It seems clear that Jameel wants to add a ChangeHandler to a CheckBox.  Chris' answer below is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a `CheckBox` to a `HasChangeHandlers` instance since it doesn't implement that interface. `CheckBox` implements `HasValueChangeHandlers` so you can cast to that if you wanted. From this snippet of code, however, the value of the cast is unclear. Since your know for a fact that `faxGen` is a CheckBox (you declare and instantiate it right above the line where you add the handlers), you should add the handler (either the valueChangeHandler or the ClickHandler) without the cast.